# Sequelize hasMany include to return object rather than array

Tags: javascript, associations, sequelize.js

Model Definitions:

```
sequelize.define('Parent', {name: DataTypes.STRING})
sequelize.define('Child', {name: DataTypes.STRING})
```

Associations:

```
Parent.hasMany(Child, {
  foreignKey: 'parent_id',
  as: 'child'
})

Child.belongsTo(Parent)
```

Include function:

```
Parent.findByPk(pk, {
  include: [{
    model: Child,
    as: 'child',
    where: {
      name: 'benny'
    }
  }]
})
```

What it returns (usual behavior):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "parent name",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": 2
      "name": "benny",
      "parent_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

What I wish it to return (I do not see any support or mention in docs)

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "parent name",
  "child": {
    "id": 2
    "name": "benny",
    "parent_id": 1
  }
}
```

Difference is `Child` is configured to return as object

Has anyone met this challenge?

Comment: its a one to many relationship ....i failed to see how this is possible

Comment: how can you return an array? I just intend the opposite! I failed to include all results (as array), sequelize always return only one (as object)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Parent.hasOne(Child, {
  foreignKey: 'parent_id',
  as: 'child'
})

else it is an array because the parent can have more than one.

Parent.hasMany(Child, {
  foreignKey: 'parent_id',
  as: 'children'
})

If you really only care about the first child or single.. Parent.children[0]

You can tack on your own function to the Parent called child that returns just that first one in the children array.  Or latest one by date.. its up to you on that function.